# How would you validate emails in a minimal API project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

Using `[EmailAddress]` in a controller-based API is sufficient to also include email validation errors (as far as I know), however doing the same in a minimal API doesn't have that feature. A colleague suggested that this is the case because minimal APIs don't have support yet for IModelValidator.
How would you address this issue?

So far I've tried using [jsteadfast/EmailValidation](https://github.com/jstedfast/EmailValidation), but it seems to fail me. I attempted to use `[Email]` on top of a string I wanted to validate, however that doesn't seem to have the effect I wanted.

Comment: _"Using [EmailAddress] in a controller-based API is sufficient to also include email validation errors"_ - **No, it's not**: the regex used internally by that attribute was critically nerfed a few years ago due to a denial-of-service attack vulnerability. See here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/28501

Comment: Is  your question how to apply automatic validation on a model, or is your question how to "validate" (whatever that means) an email address?

Comment: From experience,  I'd say it is much less hassle to just require one single "@" be present in the string. Then include in the process that an actual mail is sent to that address and reception _must_ be confirmed either by confirmation link or some PIN inside that mail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Dai thank you, I was unaware. How would you go about validating?

Comment: @BurnsBA my question is what are the current solutions for email validation given the context I described

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the 'minimal API project' you mentioned means. Assuming you want to validate an email address without any dependency but only system libraries.

If you want to know if a string is an Email address, simply call:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

bool isValid = new EmailAddressAttribute().IsValid("someone@somedomain.com");
```

In case you want to validate a class which has Email address as a property, which is common in API projects:

You can try to add a static validator first:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public static (bool isValid, string[] errors) Validate(object input)
{
    var context = new ValidationContext(input);
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

    if (Validator.TryValidateObject(input, context, results, true))
    {
        return (true, Array.Empty<string>());
    }
    else
    {
        return (false, results.Select(t => t.ErrorMessage).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Then build a model to be validated:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Widget
{
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} is required!")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "The {0} requires min length: {1}")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 100)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can validate it directly in `Main()` or any controller action code.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var widget = new Widget
    {
        Email = "someone@somedomain.com",
        Price = 1557,
        Name = "test"
    };

    var (isValid, errors) = Validate(widget);

    Console.WriteLine($"Is valid: {isValid}");

    foreach (var error in errors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(error);
    }
}
```

[image: demo validate in cosnole app]

Comment: ```csharp
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;  
 
bool isValid = new EmailAddressAttribute().IsValid("someone@somedomain.com");  
```

Can you do this with just a single data annotation on top, ala `[EmailAddress]`? Because I assumed it already did that.

Answer (score 0):

> A colleague suggested that this is the case because minimal APIs
> don't have support yet for IModelValidator. How would you address this
> issue?

Using this package [O9d.AspNet.FluentValidation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/O9d.AspNet.FluentValidation) that's built on top of [FluentValidation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/) this can be achieved easily for minimal api's.

Firstly, you will need to add the following packages:

```
dotnet add package FluentValidation.AspNetCore --version 11.3.0
```

and

```
dotnet add package O9d.AspNet.FluentValidation --version 0.1.1
```

Add the validator to your Model like this:

```
public class CustomerRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }

    public string? Email { get; set; }

    public class Validator : AbstractValidator<CustomerRequest>
    {
        public Validator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Email).EmailAddress().WithMessage("Please provide valid email"); ;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `Program.cs` add this to register the validators:

```
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Program>();
```

Last step then is to add the attribute `[Validate]`  to the request and the method `WithValidationFilter()` which can either be added to the route group  i.e:

```
var root = app.MapGroup("core").WithValidationFilter();
```

or the router handler itself:

```
root.MapPost("/weatherforecast", ([Validate] CustomerRequest customer) =>
{
    return customer;
}).WithValidationFilter();
```